# $.each unable to append data to formData() , in spite of key value being populated

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following HTML form:

```
<form action="mail/filesend.php" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data" validate>
    <div class="input-wrpr">
        <input type="file" name="files">
    </div>
    <button type="submit">
        Send File
    </button>       
</form>
```

and I have the following change event attached to the file input:

```
let files = null; // Global variable

$('input[type="file"]').on('change' , (e) => {
    files = e.target.files;
});
```

I have the following code in my submit handler:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    let data = new FormData();

    console.log(data);
    $.each(files, function(key, value) {
        data.append(key, value);
    });
    console.log(data);

});
```

Notice how I `console.log` the data before and after the `$.each` loop, the problem I am encountering here is that before and after the `$.each` loop there is no data appended to the `data` variable at all. Why is this happening?

If I `console.log` the key , value I get `0` as the key and and object that looks like the below as the value:

```
File {name: "IMO.pdf", lastModified: 1501150320000, lastModifiedDate: Thu Jul 27 2017 15:42:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 5941320, …}
```

Why is `$.each` loop unable to append data to my `data` variable ?

Comment: But what you expect in data variable?. If files is an array then key is the index. Example 0,1,2...

Comment: @MTK i expect after the $.each loop is run that somewhere in the object logged i get the following `File {name: "IMO.pdf", lastModified: 1501150320000, lastModifiedDate: Thu Jul 27 2017 15:42:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 5941320, …}`

Comment: That what you get, I have understand ... but what you expect  in your data variable? Only the name of file ? or Name and  size ... etc Or all about the file?

Comment: @MTK , somewhere in the `data` i expect that i get a key with an object that looks like: `File {name: "IMO.pdf", lastModified: 1501150320000, lastModifiedDate: Thu Jul 27 2017 15:42:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 5941320, …}`

Comment: Ok. Then see mi answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `console.log(data.getAll('0'))` to check the `data` object for the file.

Just using `console.log(data)` is insufficient.

Comment: Thank you , very insightful , worked for me , give me sometime to accept :)

Comment: How come when i console.log(data) , i see an empty object though `FormData {}``, a bit mystified .

Comment: I tested your code, as written in the question, with Firefox. `console.log(data)` returned the FormData object, but calling `.getAll('0')` returned details of the file I tried uploading. So I'm not sure why you're seeing an empty object.

Answer (score 2):

Im not shure why your code is failing, however 0,1,2... may not be good parameters. May do this:

```
$.each(files, function(key, value){
        data.append("files[]",value,value.name);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**First** of all if your input accept multiple files you need to add `[]` to your name `attr`

```
<input type="file" name="files[]" id="my-inptu">
```

**second** we will add the files variable to your submit handler:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    let files = $("#my-input")[0].files;
    let data = new FormData();

    console.log(data);
    $.each(files, function(key, value) {
        data.append(files[key].name, value);
    });

    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Thank you , very insightful !

Answer (score 1):

This can working to you ?

```
$.each(files, function(key, value){
        data.append("files[]",value);
});
```